# How to determine which lambda is being throttled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I see on our dashboard we have some throttles:

[image]

How do I determine WHICH of the thousands of lambdas we have is being throttled?

In CloudWatch metrics, I am forced to enter the function name for the throttle metric, and do to this each lambda would take forever.

Maybe a boto3 script? Maybe there IS a way via CloudWatch Metrics?

Comment: Its best practice to setup cloudwatch alarm on your lambda if you are setting a concurrency for it so that you get notified every time it gets throttled and take appropriate action.

Comment: Yup. For new lambdas, that is we do.  The problem is that there are close to 2K lambdas that don't have individual cloudwatch alarms.  I'm trying to find that needle in the haystack that is being throttled.

Comment: go to Cloudwatch metrics for lambda, select `By Function Name`, and filter by Throttles. Select all lambdas, select the time range when you are facing the issue and you can find out which lambda is being throttled. You can view 100 lambdas at a time. It won't take much time to look for 2k lambda. This is the best you can do now to find the culprit.